# How can i get the settings value of the FTP server through java code?

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I want to know the setting value of the FTP server from the client state.

(using FTPClinet, Apache Commons-Net library)

for example

among the setting value of the FTP server

```
idle_session_timeout=300
pasv_enable=YES
```

I want to get the above FTP server setting value through FTPClient in Java(apache commons-net)

Is it possible to obtain the setting value of the FTP server from the client state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no generic way to retrieve arbitrary settings of an arbitrary FTP server from a client side.

There might be specific ways to *detect* (not read) specific settings, but that will differ per settings. So you will have to ask specific question for each setting you are interested in. *If you do that, make sure you explain, why you even want to know the value of the setting.*

---

Though, you have asked the question about the active/passive mode already:
[Is there a way to tell if the FTP server is active or passive in the Java web program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56266683/850848)
*(albeit under a different account)*

Comment: I want two value of the setting on the FTP server. The first is idle_session_timeout. Second, it is to confirm whether the FTP server is passive mode. Can the client know this? I want to know if I should use FTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode or FTPClient.enterLocalActiveModein the client state. Is there a way to detect it, not read?

Comment: You have asked that question already: [Is there a way to tell if the FTP server is active or passive in the Java web program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56266683/850848)

Comment: No server will ever have `pasv_enable=NO`, that makes no sense (and `YES` is the default). If you want to detect anyway: Again, as I wrote above, ask a specific question about detecting passive mode.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer :) Wasn’t pasv_enable=NO meant the active mode?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to discuss active/passive mode at this *broad* question. If you want to discuss active/passive, comment on your other *specific* question. Or ask a new question.