# How to enter FTP server's passive mode or active mode through FTPClient

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

Client is entering passive mode first, because I don't know if the Remote FTP-server is active-mode or passive-mode.

Generally, one enters passive mode first.

The code is as follows:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect(ip,port);
ftpClient.login(id,pw);
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
...
(occur mode error)
(I use try-catch in case an error occurs)
(active mode reconnect)
...
ftpClient.logout();
ftpClient.disconnect();
ftpClient.connect(ip,port);
ftpClient.login(id,pw);
ftpClient.enterLocalActiveMode();
```

I want to hear the right thing to do with mode processing like this.

I'm using FTPClient (Apache Commons Net).

Comment: I have already wrote in an answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56266683/850848) (although posted using a different account) that FTP servers are not active or passive. It's not a switch. Most servers support both modes. You keep asking a wrong question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In active mode FTP the server must open a TCP connection back to the client; unless your client is directly on the internet (with no firewall or address forwarding) then active mode will not work.

In contrast, passive mode FTP does not open a TCP socket from the server to the client and will work in both cases (direct internet connection, and internet connection through address forwarding).

Most computers are behind a firewall **and** use address forwarding, so passive mode is usually the way to go.

Comment: You mean if TCP connection is open to clients, clients are right to access using ftpCliant.enterLocalActiveMode() instead of ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode()

Comment: FTP opens a command channel from the client to the server in all cases; for sending DATA one of two options are available. Either the PORT command is used (entering active mode) and opening a connection from the server to the client, or the PASV command is used (entering passive mode) and opening a connection from the client to the server. In both cases, that second channel is actually used to send the data.

Comment: Is the FTP server setting determining a passive-mode server or an active-mode server? or Does the FTP server provide both modes (active-mode or passive-mode) and allow client to choose?

Comment: The second one. The client chooses.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer.. I know that in FTP server settings I use passive-mode by adding pasv_enable=YES(using vsftpd). In the end, if I do not add pasv_enable=YES to the FTP server setting, it is only possible to PORT(active-mode)? If the FTP server first sets the past_enable=YES, will the client choose passive-mode or active-mode?

Comment: You would have to try it; if you disable passive-mode in the server then you will break a large number of ftp clients. Just as FTP servers might be configured to remove support for functionality, so can ftp clients. To reiterate, if you are connecting to the server over the internet active mode ftp will only work if the client is **directly** connected to the internet. What does "only work" mean? It means, the client will connect; try to set the PORT; and there will be no data channel - so it won't be able to send or receive data.